# style option in select with ng-options

Tags: angularjs, select

I need style to option (similar AngularJs Material), which inside select with ng-options. How I can do it? What is the best and simple way?

index.html:

```
<select ng-model="$ctrl.orderBy" 
ng-options="option.name for option in $ctrl.options.sort">
</select>
```

contoller.js :

```
this.options = {
            sort: [
                {
                    name: 'alphabetically',
                    value: 'name',
                    reverse: false
                },
                {
                    name: 'index',
                    value: 'code',
                    reverse: false
                }                
            ]
        };

this.orderBy = this.options.sort[0];
```

Comment: You'll probably need to use an `ng-repeat` and build out each `<option>` instead of using `ng-options`.

Comment: what styles you need to apply ?

Comment: change custom style

Comment: What have you tried? You can do this in CSS pretty readily.

Comment: @HereticMonkey really? how? I tried and no results.

Comment: Depends on how it's rendered, but if it's the standard HTML `select`: `select { font-size: 18px; } option[value="name"] { text-decoration: underline; }`. You don't say anything about how you want it styled, so it's impossible to answer fully.